# Bootstrap cards go under a another section

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

**Goal**

I am aiming to get the mobile version of each section to display properly.

**Problem**

I am having this annoying issue:

**Full width (All good, looking good)**

[image]

**Mobile version (Not good)**

The section separates here:

[image]

The bootstrap cards go into the next section, which it shouldn't do.

And also, when at contact-me form, you are able to see the bootstrap card being under:

[image]

**HTML & CSS**

```css
 /* ------------ PROJECTS ------------  */

#projects {
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)) ,url('../img/_DSC0031.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
}


#projects .title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

#projects h1{
    font-size: 5rem;
    padding-top: 5rem;
}

#projects .card {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    transition: .5s;
}



#projects .card:hover {
    background-color: #512da8;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

  /* ------------ Contact me ------------  */

#contact-me {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)) ,url('../img/IMG_1790.JPG');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#contact-me form {
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  padding: 25px;
}

#contact-me button {
  background-color: #512da8 !important;
}


  @media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    #about-me .container {
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: 2rem;
      margin-bottom: 5rem;
      left: 0%;
    }
  
    #about-me video {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin-right: 0rem;
      object-position: right;
    }
  
    #about-me .text {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">  
  
  <!-- Main Layout-->
  <main>
    <section id="projects" data-aos="fade-in">
      <div class="container ">
        <div class="title">
          <h1>PROJECTS</h1>
        </div>
        <hr class="hr-light mb-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card text-center">
              <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                  <source src="video/Cest La Vie_Trim.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              </video>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Filmography</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card text-center">
              <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                  <source src="video/STUCCO III_Trim.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              </video>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Photography</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card text-center">
              <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                  <source src="video/A Badly Rolled J -2_Trim.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              </video>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Script Writing</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card text-center">
              <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                  <source src="video/Cest La Vie_Trim_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              </video>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Reviews</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="contact-me" data-aos="fade-in">
      <div class="container">
        <form>
          <h1>Contact me</h1>
          <label>Full Name</label>
          <div class="row">
            
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="e.g name98@gmail.com">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Your message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="3" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>


  </main>
  <!-- Main Layout-->
```

**Question**

What Im I doing wrong? Where in my css have I went wrong to make this awkward bootstrap card? And also, in the future - what should I keep in mind when separating sections?

Comment: what bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: @Bellian v.4.5 sir

Comment: Hmm looks like a overflow Problem..
You can try to add a media query for smaller screens and set the height of the container (`projects `) to auto and position the background image fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove the height limitation on smaller devices.

At the moment you limit the size of the containers `#projects` and `#contact-me` to 100vh.

You can remove this limit on smaller screens (first example `#projects`) or use a min-height (second example `#contact-me`).

If the size of the containers are mandatory, you can use `overflow: auto`, so the content inside this container is also scrollable (thirdexample `#projects2`).

```js
/*
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579546929518-9e396f3cc809?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI0MX0&w=1000&q=80
*/
```

```css
#projects {
    position: relative;
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579546929518-9e396f3cc809?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI0MX0&w=1000&q=80);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
}

#projects2 {
    position: relative;
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579546929518-9e396f3cc809?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI0MX0&w=1000&q=80);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow:auto;
}


#projects .title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

#projects h1{
    font-size: 5rem;
    padding-top: 5rem;
}

#projects .card {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    transition: .5s;
}



#projects .card:hover {
    background-color: #512da8;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

  /* ------------ Contact me ------------  */

#contact-me {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)) ,url('../img/IMG_1790.JPG');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#contact-me form {
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  padding: 25px;
}

#contact-me button {
  background-color: #512da8 !important;
}


@media only screen and (max-height: 1024px) {
  #projects {
    height: auto;
  }
  
  #about-me .container {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    left: 0%;
  }

  #about-me video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 0rem;
    object-position: right;
  }

  #about-me .text {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">  

<main>
  <section id="projects" data-aos="fade-in">
    <div class="container ">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>PROJECTS</h1>
      </div>
      <hr class="hr-light mb-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card text-center">
            <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                <source src="video/Cest La Vie_Trim.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Filmography</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card text-center">
            <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                <source src="video/STUCCO III_Trim.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Photography</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card text-center">
            <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                <source src="video/A Badly Rolled J -2_Trim.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Script Writing</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card text-center">
            <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                <source src="video/Cest La Vie_Trim_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Reviews</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="contact-me" data-aos="fade-in">
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <h1>Contact me</h1>
        <label>Full Name</label>
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="e.g name98@gmail.com">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message">Your message</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="3" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section id="projects2" data-aos="fade-in">
    <div class="container ">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>PROJECTS</h1>
      </div>
      <hr class="hr-light mb-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card text-center">
            <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                <source src="video/Cest La Vie_Trim.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Filmography</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card text-center">
            <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                <source src="video/STUCCO III_Trim.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Photography</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card text-center">
            <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                <source src="video/A Badly Rolled J -2_Trim.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Script Writing</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card text-center">
            <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                <source src="video/Cest La Vie_Trim_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Reviews</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


</main>
<!-- Main Layout-->
```

Comment: Lovely stuff! :D Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem :) I updated and you have 3 options now ;)

Comment: This will definitely help me in future projects :D